# What's the fastest algorithm to find the median for numbers on different machines?

Tags: algorithm

If I have `m` machines, and an equal number `n` of numbers on each machine, what is the fastest algorithm to find the median of ALL of these numbers, i.e., all of the `m*n` numbers? There are two cases I'd like to look at: each `n` numbers sorted or unsorted.

Does anyone have some references, or some ideas to share? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Median of medians can be adapted over multiple machines, especially if they all have the same number of elements.

Michael's solution is an adaptation of quickselect.  They both work, but quickselect is usually faster, despite being O(nlogn) compared to median of median's O(n).

Comment: Which exactly complexity of quickselect do you mean? IIRC its average complexity is O(n).

Comment: @maxim Big-oh notation implies worst-case.  And I misremembered: quickselect is actually O(n^2), but will usually finish in O(n), with a much smaller constant than median of medians.

Comment: @bdares: when you say "median of medians", how do you actually do that on multiple machines? Can you provide some details please?

Comment: @Qiang Median of medians is a recursive algorithm; it tosses out (at least) 1/10 of the list each iteration.  An obvious parallelization technique would be to find the median on each machine, then to generate new lists of those medians (on fewer participating machines).